# Preserve Formatting in Master Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am gathering data from multiple workbooks into master workbook. I want to preserve the format of the text in my master workbook as it is in my source workbooks. Can Anybody help?

Comment: While pasting the data just use "Paste Special" & "Value". if you are doing this using VBA, the paste line should be Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: Are you copying sheets from the multiple workbooks into one worksheet or a separate worksheet for each workbook that is copied in? Have you got any code at all that you can post?

Comment: @J.B. you just described the exact opposite of what the OP wants to achieve. He would like to preserve the format `...as it is in my source workbook`. Hence, he should copy it over including the format (an not the values only as you described) and any possible conditional formatting. Yet, the way to go is pretty much the same. Just use something along the following: `wbSource.Range("A1:C10").Copy Destination:=wbDestination.Range("A1:C10")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how you copy from one workbook to another, keeping the source formatting. You can adjust the range and the name of the workbook as necessary.

```
Workbooks("source").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
Workbooks("destination").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys. I am successful :)

Comment: Glad to help! If you could mark this as the right answer, I am trying to build up my reputation and it would help a lot. Thanks!